# call onCreateOptionsMenu from listview adapter class in android

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

I want to update the cart in action bar when clicking the list view button in adapter class.just like grocery shopping apps.

Comment: what you areusing textview ??

Comment: textview and buttons(as a number picker)

Comment: Pass in a reference to your activity: [How to use Activity Methods in RecyclerView Adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34465325)

Comment: thanks JonasCz , it solved my problam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on your `Activity`. So if you have access to the `Activity` from your `adapter`, just do that and everything should work just fine.

EDIT:

If you don't have access to the `Activity` from `adapter` then create one.
For example with a `Listener` passed to the `adapter` constructor.

---

`ExampleAdapter` (just the essential parts, there might not be all methods needed, do them yourself):

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private Listener listener;

    public ExampleAdapter(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // other needed methods

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onOptionsMenuChangeRequested();
                }
            }
        });
        //some other stuff
    }

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public Button button;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // initialize the button
        }
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void onOptionsMenuChangeRequested();
    }
}
```

If you create the `adapter` in a `Fragment`:

```
ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(new ExampleAdapter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuChangeRequested() {
        if (getActivity() != null){
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
});
```

Or if you create the `adapter in a`Activity`:

```
ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(new ExampleAdapter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuChangeRequested() {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not having access to Activity calling adapter from fragment.

Comment: I am want to develop app like grocery apps.with navigation drawer, on click  navigation item listview displays, where i can add product or delete products from cart.

Comment: The exact case of yours seems like much too broad question, so I'll the question from your title (since it seems like you're most definitely heading in the right direction).

Comment: Oh. Just realized you're using a `ListView` and not a `RecyclerView`. Anyhow the approach should be exactly the same.